# React bootstrap - Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-bootstrap

I am using `Bootstrap` with `ReactJS` in order to learn the latter.

I  want to diplay a Bootstrap Navbar in my app.

My code is the following:

**app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
          <img
            alt=""
            src="####"
            width="30"
            height="30"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
          />
        // {' React Bootstrap'}
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
    integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <title>My app</title>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" 
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import $ from 'jquery';
import Popper from 'popper.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

But I get:

> > Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

I did some research and people suggest that the error is caused by different version of React.
So I run `npm ls react` but I get only one version:

```
myapp-frontend@0.1.0 /Desktop/myapp-frontend
└── react@16.10.2
```

As suggested in comment, if I run `npm ls react-dom` I get this:

```
myapp-frontend@0.1.0 /Desktop/myapp-frontend
└── react-dom@16.10.2
```

Comment: Not different versions of `react` but of `react-dom`. Run `npm ls react-dom` to verify. It has to be `>=16.8.0` and should match your version of `react`.

Comment: Thanks, I still get one version:
`myapp-frontend@0.1.0 myapp-frontend
└── react-dom@16.10.2 
 `

Comment: where are you getting this error? Can you post full stack trace of error which will point out what is throwing such error

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove this out of your code please

// {' React Bootstrap'}

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">

      <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">
          <img
            alt=""
            src="####"
            width="30"
            height="30"
            className="d-inline-block align-top"
          />
        </Navbar.Brand>
      </Navbar>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I think the error is coming from that line

Comment: As the error already point out you can only use hook inside your functional component not class component

Comment: I do not use it, everything I posted it is exactly my app. I started a new react app, and add the code you see into it. Therefore it has no other code inside.

Comment: Can you try to delete the Navbar.Brand tag ? If that is not working can you share your code in github for me ?